# How to extract sections of specific text from PDF files into R data frames? Complex

Tags: r, regex, text-extraction, data-extraction

**Please any advice will be appreciated.. This is time sensitive.** I have PDF reports that are mostly blocks of text. They are long reports (~50-100 pages).  I'm trying to write an R script that is capable of extracting specific sections of these PDF reports using start/stop positional strings. NOTE: Reports vary in length. Short example:

```
DOCUMENT TITLE
01. SECTION 1
This is a test section that I DONT want to extract. 
This text would normally be much longer... Over 100 words.
Sample Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

02. SECTION 2
This is a test section that I do want to extract. 
This text would normally be much longer... Over 100 words.
Sample Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
...

11. SECTION 11
This is a test section that I do want to extract. 
This text would normally be much longer... Over 100 words.
Sample Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
...

12. SECTION 12
This is a test section that I DONT want to extract. 
This text would normally be much longer... Over 100 words.
Sample Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
...
```

So the goal in this example, is to extract the paragraph below Section 2 and store it as a field/data point. I also want to store Section 11 as a field/data point. **Note the document is in PDF format**

I have tried used pdftools, tm, stringr, I've literally spent 20+ hours searching for solutions and tutorials on how to do this. I know it is possible as I have done it using SAS before...

Please see code below, I added comments with questions. I believe RegEx will be part of the solution but i'm so lost.

```
# Init Step
libs <- c("tm","class","stringr","testthat",
          "pdftools")
lapply(libs, require, character.only= TRUE)


# File name & location
filename = "~/pdf_test/test.pdf"

# converting PDF to text
textFile <- pdf_text(filename) 

cat(textFile[1]) # Text of pg. 1 of PDF
cat(textFile[2]) # Text of pg. 2 of PDF

# I'm at a loss of how to parse the values I want. I have seen things 
  like:

sectionxyz <- str_extract_all(textFile, #??? )

rm_between()

# 1) How do I loop through each page of PDF file?
# 2) How do I identify start/stop positions for section to be extracted?
# 3) How do I add logic to extract text between start/stop positions
#    and then add the result to a data field?
# 4) Sections in PDF will be long sections of text (i.e. 100+ words into a field)
```

NEW------

So I have been able to:
-Prep doc correctly
-Identify the correct start/stop patterns:

`length(grep("^11\\. LIMITS OF LIABILITY( +){1}$",source_main2))
length(grep("Applicable\\s+[Ll]imits\\s+[Oo]f",source_main2))`

`pat_st_lol <- "^11\\. LIMITS OF LIABILITY( +){1}$"
pat_ed_lol <- "Applicable\\s+[Ll]imits\\s+[Oo]f"`

The `length(grep())` statements verify only 1 instance is being found. From here I am kind of lost based on how to use gsub or similar to extract the portion of data I want. I tried:

`pat <- paste0(".*",pat_st_lol,"(.*)",pat_ed_lol,".*")
test <- gsub(".*^11\\. LIMITS OF LIABILITY( +){1}$(.*)\n",
             "Applicable\\s+[Ll]imits\\s+[Oo]f", source_main2)
test2 <-gsub(".*pat_st_lol(.*)\npat_ed_lol.*")`

So far, little progress, but progress anyways.

Comment: I've tried a number of approaches when it comes to converting pdf to text... However the text is simply stored as a 'Value" in RStudio. I really need to be able to IDENTIFY START POSITION (where to start extracting string) --> START EXTRACTING STRING INTO DATAFRAME --> IDENTIFY END POSITION (where to stop extracting string)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can come with a systematic to identify the sections you need, you could, as you indicated, use Regex to extract the text you want.

In your above example, something like `gsub(".*SECTION 11(.*)\n12\\..*","\\1",string)` ought to work.

Now you could define patterns dynamically using `paste` and iterate through all files. Each result can then be saved in your `data.frame, list,...`.

---

Here is a <s>brief</s> more detailed explanation of the pattern:

- Firstly, `.*` is way of matching "anything". If you want to match digits you can use `\\d` or equivalently `[0-9]`. [Here](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html) is a short intro to Regex in R (which I found to be quite useful) where you can find several character classes.
- `.*` at the edges of the pattern means that there can be text before/after
- `(.*)` denotes the content we want (so here matching any content as `.*` is used). Basically it means extract "anything" between `SECTION 11` and `12.`
- `\\.` means the dot and `\n` is the "newline" metacharacter (as before "12.", a new line is started)
- In Regex you can create groupings within your pattern using the brackets, i.e. `gsub(".*(\\d{2}\\:\\d{2})", "\\1","18.05.2018, 21:37")` will return `21:37`, or `gsub("([A-z]) \\d+","\\1","hello 123")` will give `hello`.
- Now the second argument in `gsub` can and is often used to provide a substitute, i.e. something to replace to matched pattern with. Here however, we do not want any substitue, we want to extract something. `\\1` means extract the first grouping, i.e. what it inside the first brackets (you could have multiple groupings).
- Finally, `string` is the string from which we want to extract, i.e. the PDF file

Now if you want to perform something similar in a loop you could do the following:

```
# we are in the loop
# first is your starting point in the extraction, i.e. "SECTION 11"
# last is your end point, i.e. "12."

first <- "SECTION 11"   # first and last can be dynamically assigned 
last <- "12\\."         # "\\" is added before the dot as "." is a Regex metachar
# If last doesn't systematically contain a dot
# you could use gsub to add "\\" before the dot when needed:
# gsub("\\.","\\\\.",".") returns "\\."
# so gsub("\\.","\\\\.","12.") returns "12\\."

pat <- paste0(".*",first,"(.*)","\n",last,".*")  #"\n" is added to stop before the newline, but it could be omitted (then "\n" might appear in the extraction)
gsub(pat,"\\1",string) # returns the same as above
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. It seems promising, I'm going to test your suggestion now and will let you know the outcome. I need to look up gsub as I dont have a strong understanding of it. I.e. where you listed _string_, I can't tell if that is defining the type: string or if its a sample word for something more meaningful. Will post results soon.

Comment: @J.Koren I forgot about the `\n` elements that can be found in strings. I edited my `gsub`, see above.

Comment: I havent performed a full test yet... I'm really having difficulty understanding the brief explanation of the pattern -- to which is very important that I do... I understand: `.*` to be the edges; `(.*)` content we want, the in-between; `\\.` being the period... but some of the other stuff I am having a bit of struggle figuring out... Hm I'm just wondering if there is anyway to identify the ##. ( or 11./12.) dynamic, based on position to the section name.

Comment: @J.Koren I have added more details concerning the pattern, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately due to organizational restrictions I won’t be able to test until Monday. I will definitely let you know how it goes. The goal is to loop through a folder of reports extracting the same sections from each one. I’m going to put your proposed answer to the test on just 1 report for now and move on from there. I wasn’t expecting to receive so much help. Thanks again.

Comment: I am able to grep the start/stop patterns for my actual report. As such: `pat_st_lol <- "^11\\. LIMITS OF LIABILITY( +){1}$"
pat_ed_lol <- "Applicable\\s+[Ll]imits\\s+[Oo]f"` I tested the accuracy using `length(grep("^11\\. LIMITS OF LIABILITY( +){1}$",source_main2))` which returns 1 instance. How do I add this into gsub to extract the text between these two patterns?

Comment: I just want to add something because I struggled a lot with it: if you want to extract multiple groupings - 3 for instance -, you must specify `replacement = "\\1\\2\\3"`.